# Python & JSON Phrasing issues

Tags: python, json

I am having issues phrasing the TwitchAPI JSON. I am trying to read the `name` which is under multiple layers (not Sure of the correct term for this).

Here is part of the API JSON:

```
{
"_links": {
    "next": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/test_user/follows?direction=DESC&limit=25&offset=25",
    "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/test_user/follows?direction=DESC&limit=25&offset=0"
},
"_total": 336,
"follows": [
    {
        "_links": {
            "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/test_follower/follows/channels/test_user"
        },
        "created_at": "2014-07-24T20:21:10Z",
        "user": {
            "_id": 00000001,
            "_links": {
                "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/test_follower"
            },
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": "2014-07-05T17:27:45Z",
            "display_name": "test_follower",
            "logo": null,
            "name": "test_follower",
            "type": "user",
            "updated_at": "2014-07-24T20:20:29Z"
        }
    },
```

Etc, it continues with multiple `name` values I wish to collect.

How do I get the `name` item? This is my current attempt:

```
print [data['name'] for data in data['follows']['user']]
```

But this just gives the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data['follows']` is a `list`, you can't use `['user']` to get the element in this list.
You need a loop or using `data['follows'][0]` to get

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/test_follower/follows/channels/test_user"
    },
    "created_at": "2014-07-24T20:21:10Z",
    "user": {
        "_id": 00000001,
        "_links": {
            "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/test_follower"
        },
        "bio": null,
        "created_at": "2014-07-05T17:27:45Z",
        "display_name": "test_follower",
        "logo": null,
        "name": "test_follower",
        "type": "user",
        "updated_at": "2014-07-24T20:20:29Z"
    }
}
```

So, `data['follows'][0]['user']` will get you

```
"user": {
        "_id": 00000001,
        "_links": {
            "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/test_follower"
        },
        "bio": null,
        "created_at": "2014-07-05T17:27:45Z",
        "display_name": "test_follower",
        "logo": null,
        "name": "test_follower",
        "type": "user",
        "updated_at": "2014-07-24T20:20:29Z"
    }
```

then you append `[name]` after it to get the name of the user.

So the answer is: `print data['follows'][0]['user']['name']`

or

`print [data['user']['name'] for data in data['follows']]`

The `for` loop is not correct even if you change `data['follows']['user']` to `data['follows'][0]['user']`, since `data['name']` is not valid.

====I CANNOT COMMENT ON ANSWERS=======

The other answer is not correct because there's no `'name'` in `data['follows']`

Comment: Amazing!It works! One issue i see, which i haven't come across before is the charterer 'u' prefixing each `name`. Do you know how to remove it or tell me what it is? Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Unknow21 it means the string is in unicode. It I don't remember wrong, Twitter API returns all strings in unicode when the string may contain characters from other languages. Here is the doc about unicode in python: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that is something like:

```
print [data['name'] for data in data['follows']]
```

I hope this helps